# Question about the limit of a sequnce

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to calculate limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lbrack1+3^a+\cdots\cdots+(2n+1)^a\rbrack^{b+1}}{\lbrack2^b(1+2^b+\cdots\cdots+n^b)\rbrack^{a+1}}$$

$a,b \not=-1$

I tried Stolz,but it didn’t work.Any hints how to do that would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can use the definition of the Riemann integrals?

Comment: @xbh thanks! I think you are right! I’ll have a try!

Comment: @xbh I think the answer is $2^{a-b} \frac{(b+1)^{a+1}}{(a+1)^{b+1}}$

Comment: Seems right… I don't remember the result.

Comment: @xbh thank you ;)